# Problems reading large JSON file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have problems reading a large JSON file (2.9GB) in Ruby. I am using this code

```
json_file = File.read(filename)
results = JSON.parse(json_file)
```

and when I try to read the file I get the error:

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - <filename>
```

I have tested the same code with smaller files and it works fine. To verify that the file is written correctly I have tried to read it with python and it works.

Is there a limitation on the size of the file for JSON.parse? If so, could you recommend an alternative?

I have looked in the `msgpack` to reduce the size of the files, but unfortunately I am constraint by the fact that I cannot install gems.

Comment: `/var/folders/gp/r89xmhrj5_ngq8wtx8hthpqr0000gn/T/tr_out_1.json` Is an odd path, are you sure the file is there?

Comment: Yes. It's the temporary directory on Mac given by `Dir.tmpdir`. I use the same path in Python and I have also tried to move the file to the desktop and I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of `IO.read`.

You may split your file into smaller parts (for example, 1 gigabyte) and read them separately:

```
﻿dirname = File.dirname(filename)
`split -b 1024m #{filename} #{filename}.parts.`
Dir.chdir(dirname)
parts = Dir["#{filename}.parts.*"]
json = ''
parts.each do |partname|
  json += File.read(partname)
  File.delete(partname)
end
results = JSON.parse(json)
```

Be patient, this could take a while.